# WooCommerce Admin Status Error: wp_remote_post() failed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use a plugin (a payment gateway plugin) with woocommerce but it don't work cause of my woocommerce status. The section Remote post is mark red and the error is the following: *"Remote post: wp_remote_post() failed. contact your hosting provider."*

Here is my woocommerce status information:

```
WordPress environment
WordPress address (URL):        https://winninghouse.online/fr
Site address (URL):     https://winninghouse.online/fr
WooCommerce version:        8.6.1
WooCommerce REST API package:        8.6.1 /home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes
WooCommerce Blocks package:      11.8.0-dev /home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/
Action Scheduler package:        3.7.1 /home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler
Log directory writable:      /home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/
WordPress version:      6.4.3
WordPress multisite:        –
WordPress memory limit:     256 MB
WordPress debug mode:       –
WordPress cron:     
Language:       en_US
External object cache:      –
Server environment
Server info:        Apache
PHP version:        8.0.30
PHP post max size:      20 MB
PHP time limit:     30
PHP max input vars:     1000
cURL version:       7.61.1, OpenSSL/1.1.1k
SUHOSIN installed:      –
MySQL version:      8.0.22
Max upload size:        10 MB
Default timezone is UTC:        
fsockopen/cURL:     
SoapClient:     
DOMDocument:        
GZip:       
Multibyte string:       
Remote post:         wp_remote_post() failed. Contact your hosting provider.
Remote get:     
Database
WooCommerce database version:       8.6.1
Database prefix     wp_
Total Database Size     11.46MB
Database Data Size      7.94MB
Database Index Size     3.52MB
wp_woocommerce_sessions     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_api_keys     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_items      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_log      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_bonusquestions      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_bonusquestions_type     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_bonusquestions_useranswers      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_groups      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_league_users        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_leagues     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_matches     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_matchtypes      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_predictions     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_predictions_audit_log       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_rankings        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_rankings_bonusquestions     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_rankings_matches        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_scorehistory_s1_t1      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_scorehistory_s1_t2      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_seasons     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_shoutbox        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_stadiums        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
pool_wp_teams       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_actions      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_claims       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_groups       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_logs     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commentmeta      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_comments     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_events     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_adjustmentmeta       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_adjustments      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_customer_addresses       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_customer_email_addresses     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_customermeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_customers        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logmeta      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logs     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logs_api_requestmeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logs_api_requests        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logs_file_downloadmeta       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_logs_file_downloads      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_notemeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_notes        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_notifications        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_addresses      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_adjustmentmeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_adjustments        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_itemmeta       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_items      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_order_transactions       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_ordermeta        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_edd_orders       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.13MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_gla_attribute_mapping_rules      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_gla_budget_recommendations       Data: 0.19MB + Index: 0.14MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_gla_merchant_issues      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_gla_shipping_rates       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_gla_shipping_times       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_links        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_mailchimp_carts      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_mailchimp_jobs       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_options      Data: 2.08MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_postmeta     Data: 0.11MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_posts        Data: 3.45MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_event_log      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_records        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_table_0        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_table_158      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_table_159      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tablesome_table_171      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_relationships       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_taxonomy        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_termmeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_terms        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_usermeta     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_users        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_note_actions        Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_notes       Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_category_lookup       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_customer_lookup       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_download_log      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_addresses       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_coupon_lookup       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_operational_data        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_product_lookup      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_stats       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_tax_lookup      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_orders        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_orders_meta       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup     Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_download_directories      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_meta_lookup       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_rate_limits       Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_reserved_stock        Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_tax_rate_classes      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_webhooks      Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
Post Type Counts
attachment      33
elementor_library       2
kubio-globals       17
nav_menu_item       4
page        28
post        3
product     1
revision        82
shop_order_placehold        2
tablesome_cpt       3
testimonial     6
tss-sc      1
wp_navigation       1
wp_template     27
wp_template_part        13
wpcode      2
Security
Secure connection (HTTPS):      
Hide errors from visitors       
Active plugins (2)
WooCommerce     by Automattic – 8.6.1
WP Super Cache      by Automattic – 1.12.0
Inactive plugins (15)
Akismet Anti-spam: Spam Protection      by Automattic - Anti-spam Team – 5.3.1
CamPay EDD Payment Gateway      by CamPay – 1.3
CamPay Shortcode Payment Gateway        by Gabinho – 1.1
Campay Woocommerce Payment Gateway      by CamPay – 1.1.6
Easy Digital Downloads      by Easy Digital Downloads – 3.2.9
Elementor       by Elementor.com – 3.19.4
Google Listings and Ads     by WooCommerce – 2.6.1
Kubio       by ExtendThemes – 2.1.4
Mailchimp for WooCommerce       by Mailchimp – 3.7
Paid Memberships Pro        by Paid Memberships Pro – 2.12.10
Payment Gateway For EDD - SecurionPay       by Sajjad Hossain Sagor – 1.0.2
Tablesome       by Pauple – 1.0.30
Testimonial Slider and Showcase     by RadiusTheme – 2.3.8
WPCode Lite     by WPCode – 2.1.9
WPVulnerability     by Javier Casares – 3.1.1
Dropin Plugins (1)
advanced-cache.php      advanced-cache.php
Settings
API enabled:        –
Force SSL:      –
Currency        XAF (CFA)
Currency position       right_space
Thousand separator      
Decimal separator       ,
Number of decimals      0
Taxonomies: Product types       external (external), grouped (grouped), simple (simple), variable (variable)
Taxonomies: Product visibility      exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog), exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search), featured (featured), outofstock (outofstock), rated-1 (rated-1), rated-2 (rated-2), rated-3 (rated-3), rated-4 (rated-4), rated-5 (rated-5)
Connected to Woo.com:       –
Enforce Approved Product Download Directories:      
HPOS feature screen enabled:        
HPOS enabled:       
Order datastore:        Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\DataStores\Orders\OrdersTableDataStore
HPOS data sync enabled:     –
WooCommerce pages
Shop base:      #208 - /shop/
Cart:       #209 - /cart/
Checkout:       #210 - /checkout/
My account:     #211 - /my-account/
Terms and conditions:        Page not set
Theme
Name:       Twenty Twenty-Two
Version:        1.6
Author URL:     https://wordpress.org/
Child theme:         – If you are modifying WooCommerce on a parent theme that you did not build personally we recommend using a child theme. See: How to create a child theme
WooCommerce support:        
Templates
Overrides       /home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/block-notices/error.php,
/home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/block-notices/notice.php,
/home/www/winninghouse.online/fr/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/block-notices/success.php
Admin
Enabled Features:       activity-panels, analytics, product-block-editor, coupons, core-profiler, customer-effort-score-tracks, import-products-task, experimental-fashion-sample-products, shipping-smart-defaults, shipping-setting-tour, homescreen, marketing, mobile-app-banner, navigation, onboarding, onboarding-tasks, product-variation-management, product-virtual-downloadable, product-external-affiliate, product-grouped, product-linked, remote-inbox-notifications, remote-free-extensions, payment-gateway-suggestions, shipping-label-banner, subscriptions, store-alerts, transient-notices, woo-mobile-welcome, wc-pay-promotion, wc-pay-welcome-page
Disabled Features:      customize-store, minified-js, new-product-management-experience, product-pre-publish-modal, settings, async-product-editor-category-field
Daily Cron:      Next scheduled: 2024-03-12 14:27:59 +00:00
Options:        
Notes:      66
Onboarding:     completed
Action Scheduler
Version:    3.7.1
Data store: ActionScheduler_DBStore
Action Status       Count   Oldest Scheduled Date   Newest Scheduled Date
Complete        33  2024-03-11 14:29:23 +0000   2024-03-11 23:12:07 +0000
Failed      3   2024-03-11 14:30:33 +0000   2024-03-11 17:53:08 +0000
Pending     1   2024-03-12 14:29:23 +0000   2024-03-12 14:29:23 +0000
Status report information
Generated at:       2024-03-12 00:27:51 +00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

As you see in the status Remote Send and Get are disabled, contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable `Remote Send` and `Remote Get`.

Payment plugins use these two methods to send transaction details.